# Protocol Delegate Concept With Base Class

Tags: swift, class, delegates, protocols

I have a doubt related to protocol method and class method. below code explain the what i want to achieve,

```
protocol Test {
    func abc()
}

class Base {
    func abc() { }
}

class MyCustomClass: Base, Test {

}
```

So, question is which method `MyCustomClass` will add ?

In my scenario, i want to add `Test` protocol method as well as 'Base' class method. as of now this is allowing me to add `Base` class method with 'override' keyword.

So, does anyone know how can we access both `Test Protocol` and `Base Class` ?

Is it possible to get both method in `MyCustomClass` which are containing same name of the method ?

Comment: `Base` has `func abc()`  So Your base class has already implemented `abc()` so compiler won't complain about that. But this make no sense to use both in `MyCustomClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem not to understand what a protocol is. It is merely a contract guaranteeing that its adopter contains certain members.

So let's look at your code, which I have modified only slightly:

```
protocol Test {
    func abc()
}

class Base {
    func abc() { print("Base abc") }
}

class MyCustomClass: Base, Test {

}
```

The important thing about your code is that *it compiles*. Why? By adopting Test, MyCustomClass promises that it contains an `abc()` function. And it *keeps* that promise. How? By inheriting an `abc()` function from its superclass, Base.

As for "what happens", just try it:

```
MyCustomClass().abc() // Base abc
```

We instantiate MyCustomClass, call that instance's `abc()`, and sure enough, the `abc()` inherited from Base runs, in accordance with the laws of polymorphism.

But that has nothing to do with the protocol! The protocol is irrelevant and serves no purpose here. You could delete the protocol entirely from the example and get exactly the same result. The protocol is just a description of its adopter. It says "whoever adopts me has an `abc()` function," and sure enough, MyCustomClass adopts the protocol and *does* have an `abc()` function.